# How can I extend WebSocket types in Node.js using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to extend the following WebSocket https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/ws/index.d.ts

Whatever I try, I cannot seem to add a new property to the WebSocket

```js
// Messes with other typings in the WebSocket
declare module "ws" {
  // Tried declare class MyWebSocket extends WebSocket too
  interface WebSocket {
    id: string;
  }
}

wss.on("connection", socket => {
  const id = uuidv4();
  socket.id = id

  socket.on("message", data => {
```

I saw multiple people having this issue online but I could not find a detailed solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a custom interface - `ExtWebSocket`, the interface will extend `WebSocket`. Then cast your `socket` as `ExtWebSocket`. No need `declare module`.

```
interface ExtWebSocket extends WebSocket {
  id: string; // your custom property
}
```

Usage

```
wss.on("connection", (socket: ExtWebSocket) => { // here
  const id = uuidv4();
  socket.id = id;

  socket.on("message", data => {
    // do something
  })
});
```

Comment: This gives me `Property 'on' does not exist on type 'MyWebSocket'`

Comment: Are your sure `MyWebSocket ` extends `WebSocket `

Comment: Turns out I had to `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` and import it, otherwise it picked up the WebSocket from Node I think, thanks!

Comment: In order to stop TypeScript complaining about the `wss.handleUpgrade` callback I had to add the type to the server, like this: `private wss = new Server<ExtWebSocket>({port: 3033})`