# Type does not satisfy the constraint of class it extends

Tags: node.js, typescript, websocket, ws

I'm working on a WSS server using the [Node ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) library. Specifically, using the approach described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60933653/how-can-i-extend-websocket-types-in-node-js-using-typescript) which may or may not be relevant.

I built a prototype server that works perfectly, but when I try to bring the same code across to my regular project, it doesn't work.

I wanted an easy way to identify the origin server for any websocket request:

```
import { Server, Data, WebSocket } from "ws";

interface IIdWebSocket extends WebSocket {
    id: string;
}

export class WSSServer {

    private wss = new Server<IIdWebSocket>({ port: 8090 });
     
    // and so on
```

Now the problem I have is that when I try to build this in my real project, I get the following message in the `new Server<IIdWebSocket>` line:

```
src/wws-server.ts:24:30 - error TS2344: Type 'IIdWebSocket' does not satisfy the constraint 'typeof WebSocket'.
  Type 'IIdWebSocket' is missing the following properties from type 'typeof WebSocket': prototype, createWebSocketStream, Server, WebSocketServer, and 9 more
```

I can't see an obvious difference between the version of the code that works and the version that doesn't. I notice that looking at the [definitely typed source for the typescript library](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/ws/index.d.ts) the property it is complaining about isn't a property of `WebSocket` at all - instead it appears to be a property of the Server type.

What is happening here?

Comment: Looks like something is comparing `Websocket` with `typeof Websocket`, which aren't the same thing. I can't see in your source where this happens though, but `Websocket`, since it's a class, can already be used as a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's expecting the type of a class *constructor* and you are passing it an object type. The value `WebSocket` is a class constructor, and so `typeof WebSocket` is the type for that constructor.

```
type IIdWebSocketConstructor = typeof WebSocket & {
    new(): IIdWebSocket
}

interface IIdWebSocket extends WebSocket {
    id: string
}
```

This creates a constructor type that returns `IIdWebSocket` when constructed.

```
export class WSSServer {
    private wss = new Server<IIdWebSocketConstructor>({ port: 8090 });

    testing123() {
        this.wss.on('connection', (socket) => {
            socket.id // works
            //     ^? number
        })
    }
}
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgZQKZQG7oDRwOqoBGyEAxgNarwC+cAZlBCHAEQDuAziwNwBQvMAJ5hUcAJJiAJgWJlKMAMIQAdhxhQArqRjQ4AXjhCREOviIkKVOADJEvOA7jLUbABQBKAFzipMi-N5qfmBlGHQ6AENSUQlpczkrVAAPMOVJDjNZS3gEe0dgSW81KBCAc0D+ZMhYOFIAGwiODLxkVvQsKDtHODASjAiwuE4Mg2c2FHb0AB5YvwTFFWKtHSgAPlckaphvAA4ABgBOPbhqdz48hzC1MoBGACYAZg8u7scYAAtgDgA6Ye+VVwAclIKmc2mAKkBuFcHHm7n0qxer1esOy3wKcAA9JihtByBwLsjHNjXgA9AD8hO6p0JQWoQA)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is really just lying to the type system. The type of the `WebSocket` that is created will still be the default one, which means that even though you're claiming it has an `id` property, there won't actually be one. You should make an actual subclass of `WebSocket`.

```js
// `id` will be `undefined`
wss.on('connection', (ws) => console.log(ws.id.toUpperCase())
```

Take note of the type parameter for the server:

```js
    class Server<
        T extends typeof WebSocket.WebSocket = typeof WebSocket.WebSocket,
        U extends typeof IncomingMessage = typeof IncomingMessage,
    > extends EventEmitter {
```

It is NOT `T extends WebSocket.WebSocket`, but `T extends typeof WebSocket.WebSocket`. `typeof SomeClass` gives you the type of the class object (constructor function), not the type of an **instance** of the class. Thus, after extending the original `WebSocket` class, the generic type parameter should be `Server<typeof CustomWebSocket>`.

Also note the constructor parameter `WebSocket`. Here, you pass the custom **class**, which is then created here on connection:
https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/a57e963f946860f6418baaa55b307bfa7d0bc143/lib/websocket-server.js#L382

Full example:

```js
import { Server, WebSocket } from 'ws'

export class CustomWebSocket extends WebSocket {
  userId!: string

  sendStuff() {
    this.send('stuff')
  }
}

export class CustomWebsocketServer extends Server<typeof CustomWebSocket> {
  constructor() {
    super({
      WebSocket: CustomWebSocket,
    })
  }

  socketForUser(userId: string): CustomWebSocket | undefined {
    // this.clients is of type Set<CustomWebSocket>
    for (const socket of this.clients) {
      if (socket.userId === userId) {
        return socket
      }
    }
  }
}

const wss = new CustomWebsocketServer()

wss.on('connection', (socket) => {
  // socket is of type CustomWebSocket
  socket.sendStuff()
})
```

Final note: You don't need one, but if you add a constructor to your `WebSocket` subclass, it has to be compatible with that of the original `WebSocket` class, which is techically:

```js
constructor(...params: ConstructorParameters<typeof WebSocket>) {}
```

Comment: This is interesting - I hadn't thought of it as lying to the type system. I guess it doesn't really matter because the outcome I'm looking for is to use the id property without the Typescript compiler going off at me, Javascript won't care, but this does look more correct.

Comment: Yeah, this way, you can have custom methods, fields, whatever. It's the intended use of it. However, since you can't control the parameters passed to the constructor, even with the custom class, you still just have to know that you assigned the values somewhere before reading them.